# How to adjust the position of conditional panel in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to adjust the position of my conditional panel. Right now, the conditional panel is sticking to the left edge of my browser and I would like to shift it slightly to the right. May I know how this can be done? Below is a simplified dummy version of my shiny App.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel(p("Indicators (Dummy Ver.)"), 
        windowTitle = "Indicators"),

    sidebarLayout(
        conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==2",
            tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { width:250px; float:left;}'),
            id = "leftPanel",
            radioButtons("timeInterval", label = h3("Time Interval"),
                    choices = c("Hourly","Daily"),
                    selected = "Hourly")
            ),
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("SNES", value=1,
                    dygraphOutput("tsPlot1"),
                    h3("Header"),
                    p("Descriptions")
                ),
                tabPanel("MA", value=2,
                    dygraphOutput("tsPlot2"),
                    h3("Header"),
                    p("Descriptions")               
                ),
                id = "conditionedPanels"
            )
        )    
    )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)

x1 <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.9,-.2)),n=100)
x2 <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(0.8,0.1)),n=100)

start <- as.POSIXct("2015-08-01 08:00")
interval <- 60
end <- start + as.difftime(99, units="hours")
timeSeq <- seq(from=start, by=interval*60, to=end)


shinyServer(
    function(input, output){

        SNES <- xts(x1, order.by = timeSeq)
        names(SNES) <- c("Sentiment")

        marine <- xts(x2, order.by = timeSeq)
        names(SNES) <- c("Activities")

        output$tsPlot1 <- renderDygraph({
            dygraph(SNES,main="Sentiment",
                ylab="Frequency") %>%
                dyLegend(width = 760)  %>% 
                dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
        })

        output$tsPlot2 <- renderDygraph({
            dygraph(marine,main="Arrivals & Departures",
                ylab="Frequency") %>%
                dyLegend(width = 720)  %>% 
                dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
        })

    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ulfelder, thanks for the suggestion. Your answer helped me solved the issue. We can create a gap between the edge of the browser and the text by wrapping the content of the conditional panel in a column as shown by the code below. We need not include an extra column.

```
sidebarLayout(

    conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==2",

      column(1,
        tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { width:250px; float:left;}'),
         id = "leftPanel",
         radioButtons("timeInterval", label = h3("Time Interval"),
                choices = c("Hourly","Daily"),
                selected = "Hourly")
      )

    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can shift the conditional panel to the right by sticking an empty column to its left, like this:

```
sidebarLayout(

    conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==2",

      column(1),

      column(3,
        tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { width:250px; float:left;}'),
        id = "leftPanel",
        radioButtons("timeInterval", label = h3("Time Interval"),
                choices = c("Hourly","Daily"),
                selected = "Hourly")
      )

    ),
```

That may be a larger shift that you'd like. Unfortunately, column widths have to be integers, so you can't make the shift smaller with this approach. I think you could do finer tuning with fluid rows on both tabs, but that's a lot more work.